# Display Post value from HTML form to another HTML form

Tags: javascript, html

Quick question. I am starting learn on local storage HTML5. How can I get value from a form and display that value on another HTML form page? 
For example, I have two forms here. 
If I fill on form 1 and click submit button, and the value will display on form 2 in readable only.

I tried below:

HTML Form 1:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Save Value</title>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function saveVal() {
    var inputFirst = document.getElementById("name").value;
    localStorage.setItem("name", inputFirst);
    inputFirst = localStorage.getItem("name");
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="display.html" method="get">
<label> 
First Name:
<input name="name" size="20" maxlength="25" type="text" id="name" />
</label>

<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="saveVal()"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

HTML Form 2:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Display</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function result() {
    var storedVal = document.getElementById("name");
    storedVal.value = localStorage.getItem("name");
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form action="#">
<label>
First Name:
<input name="name" size="20" maxlength="25" type="text" id="name" readonly="readonly" />
</label>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: in display.html you didn't call function result(),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `display.html` you didn't call function result(),

try this,

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Display</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#">
<label>
First Name:
<input name="name" size="20" maxlength="25" type="text" id="name" readonly="readonly" />
</label>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var storedVal = document.getElementById("name");
    storedVal.value = localStorage.getItem("name");
</script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```